# Map, reuse a mutable key when using put

Tags: java

In order to make only one lookup to the map and reuse as much as possible my key instances I would like to know if it's legal to do this :

```java
    public static class GroupByOrdMap {
        private final Map<GroupByOrdKey, MutableInt> map = new HashMap<>();

        /**
         * Increment the value previously associated to key.
         * or add a new entry with value 1.
         * @param key the key
         * @return a reusale GroupByOrdKey or null if there is nothing to reuse
         */
        public GroupByOrdKey inc(GroupByOrdKey key) {
            MutableInt mu = new MutableInt(1);
            MutableInt prev = map.put(key, mu);
            if(prev != null) {
                mu.add(prev); // increment existing value
                // XXX : this key is mutable, but can I safely reuse this instance???
                return key;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


// Key, as it can be heavy I would like to reuse it as much as possible 
public static class GroupByOrdKey {
    private long[] ords;

    public GroupByOrdKey(int size) {
        ords = new long[size];
    }

    private void setOrd(int idx, long ord) {
        ords[idx] = ord;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(ords);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        GroupByOrdKey other = (GroupByOrdKey) obj;
        if (!Arrays.equals(ords, other.ords))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I do only one map lookup with put.
But can I reuse the GroupByOrdKey instance? Javadoc does not make it clear, value is replaced but what about the key instance?

Is there any other Map implementation that permits such usecase :

- only one map lookup
- reuse existing keys instance

Thanks

Comment: From the question and the code it is somewhat unclear if you really want to mutate a key after it has been used in a Map? (See dasblinkelights answer below). I'd propose to make `GroupByOrdKey` immutable by declaring `ords` as final and only initialise it in the constructor. Would this break your design?

Comment: The idea to reuse unused keys is to reuse the ords array, so it won't break design but I will create many ords[] arrays for nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using mutable keys in hash maps. At the very least, you need to postpone mutation of a key that has been added to a hash map until after it has been removed from the map. Otherwise, the mutated key would become "unreachable" inside the map.

Consider this sequence of events (assume for simplicity that hash code of an `int` is the `int` itself):

- Create a mutable integer `key` with the value of 5
- Add `key` to a hash map; it would be hashed into the bucket that corresponds to has code of `5`
- Set the `key` to `6`.
- Try adding `key` to the map again. At this point, the key would be hashed to the bucket for hash code of `6`, and added to the map again.
- Create a query key `queryKey`, a mutable integer with the value of `5`. Try searching the hash map with it.

At this point, the `queryKey` of `5` will no longer "connect" to the old key of `5`, even though they have the same hash code: the instance of `key` sitting at the hash bucket of `5` will not compare as equal to the `queryKey`, because `key`'s current value is `6`. Essentially, the old key and its associated map entry became unreachable.

Comment: Basically the right answer, but perhaps the question is misleading: From the given example, i cannot see where a map key is mutated! So i'd say nomoas code snippet looks good.

Comment: The GroupByOrdMap#inc javadoc states that user can reuse the key instance (especially the long[] ords array). To comment dasblinkenlight response: so let me reformulate my question : what Map.put(K key, V value) do with "key" instance in case value is replaced?

Comment: @GyroGearless You are right, the code snippet does not reveal the mutation of the key, only the mutation of the value, which is 100% valid. However, the question talks about reusing existing key instances (presumably, after mutating them) which requires very careful execution (i.e. the key must be inserted and removed before the mutation). The resultant code would be very fragile as well: a well-meaning coworker would be able to break it by seemingly innocent modifications of the code that uses mutable keys.

Comment: @nomoa When you put a value into a hash map that replaces an existing value, the existing key instance is kept in place. You can see it on line 395 in [this implementation of `HashMap.put(k, v)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Thanks, so it seems to be implementation dependant so it may not be portable and as you stated it is extremely fragile code. But it's a time critical process... I'm afraid I'll have to go with my own map/set impl.

Comment: @nomoa If this is time-critical, you may want to implement a key that copies the `ords` array on the first write. You would need to manually clone these keys as well, but since the array is not copied, the cloning itself would go fast. You might also want to store the value of hash code after computing it, and invalidate the stored hash code on modification. That's a little tricky to maintain, but the entire code would be encapsulated inside your `GroupByOrdKey`, so at least the complexity would be localized.

Answer (score 0):

It may work but it will almost certainly not be portable. The reason - it is very likely that somewhere in the `HashMap` code there will be:

```
...
if ( thisKey == thatKey ) {
  // They are the same object - they MUST be equal.
  ...
  code that will not be executed for you but you probably wish it was
}
```

and if there isn't in yours there may be in others.

Actually, it looks like you do this yourself in your `equals` method:

```
    ...
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
```